# Highlight specific cells to background color and set specific radio to checked true

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
<tr class="slots">
    <td data-col="1" js-select>
        <input class="time" type="radio"/> 1
    </td>
    <td data-col="2" js-select>
        <input class="time" type="radio"/> 2
    </td>
    <td data-col="3" js-select>
        <input class="time" type="radio"/> 3
    </td>
    <td data-col="4" js-select> 
        <input class="time" type="radio"/> 4
    </td>

</tr>
```

```
var selected = $('[js-select]')
$(selected).click(function(e){
  console.log('clicked')
  // $(this).parents().siblings('.timing').attr('checked', true)
  $(this).closest('input:radio').attr('checked', true)
})
```

[JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pukz2sca/)

When click on td cell itself, it should set the specific radio which is in same td cell to checked true. That way, it will set the whole column active to highlight to background color. 
I tried parents, siblings, closest but it set all radio to checked true on local machine.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but it's important to note that [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) goes up through the *ancestors* of an element; [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks at, and for, the descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The inputs are beneath the `td` so you need to use `find`.
2. Use `prop` for checkboxes (not `attr`)
3. You need a common `name=` attribute for groups of radio buttons to work together

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/pukz2sca/3/

```
var selected = $('[js-select]')
$(selected).click(function(e){
  console.log('clicked')
  // $(this).parents().siblings('.timing').attr('checked', true)
  $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true)
})
```

Comment: thanks but on ur fiddle, all radios are set to checked. It is not correct as I mentioned. Should be only one radio set checked true when clicked.

Comment: @Joe: Oh that. You were just missing a `name=`. That's how radio buttons know which others are connected to it. Have updated JSFiddle and answer to fix that too :)